# How to use Intersect tool in ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, java, intersection

I'm trying to use the Intersect tool in ArcObjects SDK Java with two feature classes.

Here is my code:

```
    public void intersectTwoFeatureClasses(Object in1, Object in2, Object out) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    IGpValueTableObject intersectInFeatures = new GpValueTableObject();
    intersectInFeatures.setColumns(2);
    intersectInFeatures.setValue(0, 0, in1);
    intersectInFeatures.setValue(0, 1, 1);
    intersectInFeatures.setValue(1, 0, in2);
    intersectInFeatures.setValue(1, 1, 1);
    Intersect intersect = new Intersect(intersectInFeatures, out);
    IGeoProcessorResult result = gp.execute(intersect, null);
    if(result.getStatus() != esriJobStatus.esriJobSucceeded)
        return;
}
```

But I get an Automation Exception: Item Not Found in this Collection. in 'DAO.Fields'.

The way I create my IGPValueTableObject seems to be wrong.

Does anyone know how to create it for two feature classes ?

Comment: Have a look at this [page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Using_value_tables/00010000028m000000/), it shows an alternate method for populating the ValueTable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working and simpler solution I found:

```
Intersect intersect = new Intersect(in1 + ";" + in2, out);
```

where in1 , in2 and out are strings giving the full path of input and output is a `IFeatureClass`